Can I use custom tag in Tomacat server.xml file to define a service
Is it possible to define a service inside custom tag in tomcat server.xml file?
**<CustomTag> 
     <Service name="TCService">
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8383" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" deployOnStartup="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">        
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/
      </Host> 
    </Engine>
  </Service> 
   </CustomTag>** 

